# Signal with bounded $1$-norm, unbounded $2$-norm and $\infty$-norm

Tags: normed-spaces, signal-processing

Is there a signal, with bounded $1$-norm, unbounded $2$-norm and $\infty$-norm?

Comment: Consider $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$, $x\in (0,1)$.

Comment: @Rigel Thanks ! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Did you mean "finite $\infty$-norm"?